# Subdomain DNS for different endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have a subdomain, `api.example.com`, that has 2 REST endpoints, `endpoint1` and `endpoint2`, that ideally would be hosted on different servers (Think EC2 instances for example). Is there a way to configure the DNS record (I am using Amazon Route 53) such that `api.example.com/endpoint1` and `api.example.com/endpoint2` can each point to their own server?  I don't think that is possible, but I just wanted to double check.  If it is indeed not possible, is there another way to point the 2 endpoints to the different servers (ideally using AWS)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this with DNS, but you can accomplish it with the Application Load Balancer.

Create an ALB, and point DNS at it.

Next, create two target groups, one for each endpoint, and deploy your instances (or autoscaling groups) to the appropriate target group.

The ALB will take care of the routing for you, and you can size and scale each endpoint fleet as needed.